# How to keep a custom Gedit Colour Scheme having chosen a general Light/Dark Style in the Appearance Settings tab of 22.04 (Gnome)

Tags: gedit, 22.04, appearance, xml

Having installed a clean 22.04 on disk, and applying a Dark Style Appearance...

I imported a custom Gedit XML style-scheme file (backed up from ~/.local/share/gedit/styles) into Gedit (41.0) via:
Gedit > three lines/dots button (does that have a name?!) > Preferences > Font & Colours > + 
I then select that Colour Scheme from the list shown, and it is applied immediately. All good so far.

However, after a period of time, rather than a specific action (as far as I can determine) the default Light/Dark style is reapplied without any prompt.

Is there a way to stop this happening and retain my own preferred colour scheme?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug. You need to wait until you get an update with fix for gedit.

> **22.04 Areas to look out for**
>
> - ...
> - All packages are now arm64 available – see the raspberry Pi section below.
> - `gedit text edit highlight for current line turned off. Dark themes are broken with gedit and often the text color cannot be read.`

Read out [this link](https://ubuntubudgie.org/2022/04/ubuntu-22-04-release-notes-for-20-04-upgraders/#:%7E:text=gedit%20text%20edit%20highlight%20for%20current%20line%20turned%20off.%20Dark%20themes%20are%20broken%20with%20gedit%20and%20often%20the%20text%20color%20cannot%20be%20read.) for more info.