Missing/invisible text in ubuntu
dIn Text Editor, files, and even when extracting archives. I can't see what I'm doing because I have to repeatedly highlight things to see them, It's odd and infuriating.

If I don't highlight text it'll go missing, and the same goes for file names and menus.

It's literally just called Text Editor. LibreOffice doesn't suffer this issue, nor much else. System dialogues are also effected.

Edit 2: using a different app for text doesnt solve the base problem that I dont have any custom schemes, and i 

What text editor?

possible duplicate https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405030/how-to-keep-a-custom-gedit-colour-scheme-having-chosen-a-general-light-dark-styl

This looks like a custom color scheme which conflicts with the system, setting light-on-light .. if you have applied a custom scheme, try temporarily removing it or making a new one via the menu
You may also be able to temporarily fix this or test out changes by changing the system color to be light or dark mode (opposing what you have now), or installing a better editor and ignoring the issue
